# jQuery UI - adding tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm having trouble in understanding the jQuery UI tabs with my code.

This is my HTML :

```
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top tabs3">
                <span><a href="">My Databases</a></span>
                <span class="selected ui-corner-top"><a href="">Databases Stats</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
                <div id="info-box">
                    <div class="info-box-left">
                        <h4 style="margin:0;">My Databases</h4>
                        <p>You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list_content_holder" id="tbl"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
                <div id="info-box">
                    <div class="info-box-left">
                        <h4 style="margin:0;">Databases Stats</h4>
                        <p>You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list_content_holder" id="tbl"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is CSS:

```
.tabs3 {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.tabs3 {
   border-bottom: medium none;
   padding: 6px;
}

.tabs3 span {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 9px 20px 7px;
}

.tabs3 span.selected {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f9f9f9_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% top #F9F9F9;
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/)

My problem is adding tabs to above html using jquery. I have imported jquery-ui-1.10.3 and tried to make the tabs. But its difficult to do with this HTML.

Thank you.

Comment: are you referring to this

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/?

Comment: You don't seem to be following the examples given. [JQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). Click on the 'view source'-button to see what you have to put in the html

Comment: @pvnarula Yes I referred it but can't figure it out with this kind of HTML. Thats the reason to ask this here

Comment: @TNK - Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/1/? As others have suggested, take a look at the jQuery UI docs and use the example code they give you.

Comment: @Joe you have changed HTML. But I need to have such a HTML code. because I have changed the tab styles in my prefer.

Comment: This is not how a jquery plugin works, you have to follow basic HTML structure and then initialize jquery plugin on it.

Comment: Its sloved. thanks for both answer. Joe was closed to me, So I accept it and upvotes to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fully working version in your desired style: http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/3/

You must apply your styles to the HTML that jQuery UI generates. You can't force it to use your custom HTML structure without re-writing whole parts of the library.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">My Databases</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Database Stats</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Database stats</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#main {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#main .ui-widget-header, #main.ui-widget-content, #main .ui-state-default, #main .ui-state-hover {
    background: none;
    border: none
}
#main .ui-state-default a {
    outline: none
}
#main .ui-tabs-active a {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f9f9f9_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% top #F9F9F9;
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

and `$("#main").tabs();` to initialise the tabs.

For future reference: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: can I have this HTML - `<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top tabs3">`

Comment: @TNK - no you can't. Your CSS styles have to apply to the HTML that jQuery UI generates. My fiddle CSS is very straightforward but still achieves the look you want. May I ask why you want the HTML to look like that?

Comment: I added my desired output through an image to my question. check it.

Comment: I use `ui-widget-header` class to style black color bar that is the header of tab bar

Comment: @TNK - both mine and Dejan.S' answers have shown you how to easily style the tabs. Couldn't you use that information to style the tabs yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Jquery tabs is as easy as [this (look at jsfiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/vGcTq/)

When ever I want custom styles on tabs (or any other ui), I add my own css file for it and "override" the jquery styles. You can easy get the class applied for any element of the tabs using any browsers developer tools (chrome or firebug for ff)

Let me know if you need any more explanation

**EDIT:** [this is how you override the jquery ui styles](http://jsfiddle.net/vGcTq/1/)

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    tab 1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    tab 3
  </div>
</div>


$('#tabs').tabs();


.ui-widget-header {
    background: #111 !important;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this. But I want custom styles for my tabs. Thats why I use above HTML

Comment: You get the tabs working with the setup above, then you can look in let's say Chrome developer tools and find out what class tabs/any element use and "override" those in you own css file, you place this css file after the jquery ui css. Give me a minute to edit the jsfiddle as demo.

Comment: @TNK, CSS need to correspond to HTML rendered by jquery plugin, not the opposite.

Comment: @Dejan.S exactly! I was answering to TNK. Your answer is the way to go, already upvoted ;)

Comment: @roasted, I'm sorry I realised after I posted that it was for TNK, missed that at first :)